# How can I send annotation value into @Before method?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

I want to change principal for a method annotated with my custom annotation.

1. I created my custom annotation:

   ```
   @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface RunAsUser {
   }
   ```
2. I've written special handler:

   ```
   @Aspect
   @Component
   public class RunAsUserAnnotationHandler {

       @Before("@annotation(RunAsUser)")
       public void configureAuthentication() {
             AuthenticationUtil.configureAuthentication("ROLE_USER");
       }

       @After("@annotation(RunAsUser)")
       public void clearAuthentication() {
           AuthenticationUtil.clearAuthentication();

      }
   }
   ```

   where `configureAuthentication(...)` and `clearAuthentication()` are methods which set another hardcoded principal value to `SecurityContext` and return one to the default value.

How can I modify my code if I want to set principal value as String in annotation?

I want to see smth like this:

```
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface RunAsUser {
        String userName();
    }
```

and write my code using `RunAsUser("stackoverflowUser")` but I do now know how to tranport this value to my `configureAuthentication` method from annotation.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Add an argument of type `RunAsUser` to your `configureAuthentication()` method. Get the value ("stackoverflowUser") out of this argument:

```
@Before("@annotation(runAs)")
public void configureAuthentication(RunAsUser runAs) {
      // do something with runAs.value()
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For annotation parameter binding you need to use the parameter name, not the class name in the pointcut. So the solution would be `@annotation(runAs)` in your sample code.